# How to get first title from string for the array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, octobercms

I'm trying to get all genres from movies and put these in to the select list automatically, without hard coding. So if I create a new movie in octobercms backend and add these genres "Horror, Mystery, Thriller" this show in select list just that way so I wondering how I can separate these for the select list or just pick up "Horror" in to the select list.

I just got these error all the time:

```
strtok() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

What I have doing so far:

```
 function onFilterMovies() {

 $this->prepareVars();

 }

 function prepareVars() {

 $options = post('Filter', []);

 $this['movies'] = Movie::listFrontEnd($options);


 $movies = Movie::all();
 $genres = [];

 foreach($movies as $movie) {

 $genres[] = $movie->genre;

 }

 $this['genres'] = $genres;

 }


<select class="dropdown" name="Filter[genres]"> 
    <option value="">Genres</option>
    {% for genre in genres | sort %}
    <option value="{{genre}}">{{ genre }}</option> 
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Image for the select list:

[image: Image for the select list:]

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/array_reduce) combined with [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/preg_split) to grab all the genres, then [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/array_unique) to remove duplicates:

```
$genres = array_unique(array_reduce($movies, static function ($genres, $movie) {
  $movie_genres = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $movie->genre);
  return array_merge($genres, $movie_genres);
}, []));
```

Then you'd just need to loop over that array for your select element.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/I8JQP**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Now I'm get these errors:

array_reduce() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

I edited my first post (a whole code).

Comment: @Pyramidhead85 I suppose that's a Laravel collection. Try changing the first param from `$movies` to `$movies->toArray()`? If that works, I'll edit my post with a cleaner solution (Laravel collections have a `reduce` methods themselves).

Comment: Hi, 

Can't get this working with toArray(), Undefined variable: movies etc...

Comment: @Pyramidhead85 `movies` cannot be undefined, you're looping over it in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Array explode:**

```
$title = 'a, b, c';
array_explode($title, ','); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Also you could do it Laravel Way using pluck and reduce

```php
$this['genres'] = Movie::all()->pluck('genre')->reduce(static function ($genres, $itemGenre) {
    array_merge($genres, explode(',', $itemGenre));
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I got this: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array